# how to get highest number of loop elements in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

how can I get highest numbers from loop here is my code

from this code I got

## 2

,

## 1

,

## 3

,

## 1

,

## 2

So I want

## 3

as a result could you please help me to solve this problem any help would be appriciated

```html
            {% for line_item in cart.items %}

 
            {% assign c_no = line_item.properties | join:',' | remove_first : 'meal pack,' | strip | split : '-' | last | sort: 'price' %}
            
            <h1>{{c_no}}</h1>
            
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: create custom like this code snippet, to parse the max number https://prnt.sc/QVjKHubur4Yp

Answer (score 0):

Use the `{{ forloop.length }}`

```
{% for product in collections.frontpage.products %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
  <p>This collection has {{ forloop.length }} products:</p>
  {% endif %}
  <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Docs: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/for-loops